# Xrandr not allowing me to change my screen resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, vga

I recently got a new computer, and when I installed linux on it—Ubuntu to be specific—the screen resolution was set to 1024x768. I tried adding a new mode, but when I tried switching to the new mode the screen didn't change. I have two drives on this computer—one is a ssd that has Windows installed on it, and the other is a regular hard disc that has Ubuntu installed, I am having no issue with screen resolution when I am on windows, I tried looking for help everywhere, but I couldn't find any, so this is my last option, I'm really tired right now, I was so excited when I got a new computer, now I am dealing with this crap :(

````
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
 
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
maze@rt:~$ xrandr -s 1920x1080_60.00
Failed to change the screen configuration!
maze@rt:~$ ```
````

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; are you using Xorg or Wayland?  (*release details are a good start for us to understand your software stack & thus provide advice specific to your situation*).

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the full output of `xrandr` before you ran any additional adding resolution commands and also instead of saying "I tried adding a new mode" detail EXACTLY the commands you ran etc. Also state what make/model of monitor and exactly how it is connected to your PC. Is it direct VGA cable or via an adaptor or dock? Also, this is a good resource and instructions for `xrandr`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions